# Java string.replace(old, new) count how many replaced?

Tags: java, string, replace, command

I have my console (image down below), and I have a command that will replace all oldstinrg to newstring. But how do I count how many of those were replaced?

**(If the code replaced only once a to b then it will be 1, but if it replaced a to b twice the value would be 2)**

*(this is just a part of code, but no other part is needed or any how related to this part of code)*

```
else if(intext.startsWith("replace ")){


                String[] replist = original.split(" +");    

                String repfrom = replist[1];
                String repto = replist[2];

                lastorep = repfrom;
                lasttorep = repto;

                String outtext = output.getText();
                String newtext = outtext.replace(repfrom, repto);
                output.setText(newtext);

                int totalreplaced = 0; //how to get how many replaced strings were there?

                message("Total replaced: " + totalreplaced + " from " + repfrom + " to " + repto);

            }
```

[image: My console image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use String.replaceFirst and count it yourself:

```
String outtext = output.getText();
String newtext = outtext;
int totalreplaced = 0;

//check if there is anything to replace
while( !newtext.replaceFirst(repfrom, repto).equals(newtext) ) {
    newtext = newtext.replaceFirst(repfrom, repto);
    totalreplaced++;
}

message("Total replaced: " + totalreplaced + " from " + repfrom + " to " + repto);
```

Comment: Where in this code do I put (old string) and (new string) from which will it replace and to which? Is it pattern (old) and replacement (new) or?

Comment: Ok, i did a test with this and it works... Ill add it to my Console class now and see how it works

Answer (score 7):

Your [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17218738) has few problems.

1. It will need to iterate from beginning of string every time you invoke `replaceFirst` so it is not very efficient.
2. But more importantly it can return "unexpected" results. For instance when we want to replace `"ab"` with `"a"`, for string `"abbb"` accepted solution instead of `1` will return `3` matches. It happens because:

   - after first iteration `"abbb"` will become`"abb"`
   - then in next iteration `"abb"` will become`"ab"`
   - and then `"ab"` will become `"a"`.

   So since we had 3 iterations `counter` will be `3` and that is the value which would be returned instead of `1` which is correct result.

---

To avoid this kind of problems and count only *valid* replacements in *original* string we can use `Matcher#appendReplacement` and `Matcher#appendTail`.
Demo:

```
String outtext = "abb abbb";
String repfrom = "ab";
String repto = "a";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(repfrom, Pattern.LITERAL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(outtext);

int counter = 0;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    counter++;
    m.appendReplacement(sb, repto);
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String newtext = sb.toString();

System.out.println(newtext);
System.out.println(counter);
```

Result:

```
ab abb
2
```