# How to access the replaceAllIn() counter?

Tags: scala, regexp-replace

I am using

```
val str2 = regex.replaceAllIn(str1, "other")
```

and need to count the number of replaces... There are a way retrieve  the value of the internal `replaceAllIn` counter?

PS: this is usual in other languages ([example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)), so I am supposing that Scala offer similar thing.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218661/java-string-replaceold-new-count-how-many-replaced

Comment: Hi @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, when changing from a standard Scala library (parallelizable) to a classic Java (sequential), we lost performance, is it?

Comment: sorry, I do not understand the question and how that is related to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scala> val r = "x".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = x

scala> var i = 0
i: Int = 0

scala> r.replaceAllIn("xooxxox", m => { i += 1 ; "X" })
res0: String = XooXXoX

scala> i
res1: Int = 4
```

will do `appendReplacement` under the hood.

Comment: Worth commenting that, like the other answer, it would feel more natural to `r.findAllIn(s).replacementData.foldLeft(...)((a,m) => ???)`, but the Scala API doesn't quite allow it.

Answer (score 2):

Takes another step but you could `findAllIn` and count the number found. Then do `replaceAllIn`.

```
scala> "foo".r.findAllIn("barbazfoobazfoo").size
res7: Int = 2
```

Comment: hum... So, Scala dont't offer access to basic results of the regex operation?  With `findAllIn()` will do **all again**... If I have a BigBig String that need 1 minute to do replace, will be consume more 1 minute to count?